# How can I read a ckeditor textbox instead of a normal textbox in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

How can I read a ckeditor textbox instead of a normal textbox?  My code has the ckeditor code that I tried (but do

This is the code that reads the textbox from an iframe (jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RTBJQ/12/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Copy to iframe 1 to iframe 2</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="http://fiddle.jshell.net/W88j8/show/" id="iframe1" height="600" width="500"></iframe>
        <button id="copyButton">Copy</button>
        <iframe id="iframe2" height="600" width="500"></iframe>
        <script>
            window.onload = function(){
                var iframe1 = document.getElementById('iframe1');
                var iframe2 = document.getElementById('iframe2');

                //After you will be able to use the DOM of the 2 iframes to read content
                var oDoc1 = (iframe1.contentWindow || iframe1.contentDocument);
                if (oDoc1.document) oDoc1 = oDoc1.document;
                var oDoc2 = (iframe2.contentWindow || iframe2.contentDocument);
                if (oDoc2.document) oDoc2 = oDoc2.document;

                //Where we gonna output the datas
                var outputBody = oDoc2.body;

                var copyButton = document.getElementById('copyButton');
                copyButton.onclick = function(){
            var inputs = oDoc1.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
            //var inputs =  iframe1.CKEDITOR.instances.test6.getData();
            //console.log(typeof inputs);  console.log(inputs.toString());
            outputBody.innerHTML = '<div>';
                    for (var i = 0 ; i < inputs.length ; i++){
                        outputBody.innerHTML += '<div>'+inputs[i].value+'</div>';
                    }
                    outputBody.innerHTML += '</div>';
                };
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I think this line that reads the textarea should be fixed (line 27 on jsfiddle):

```
var inputs = oDoc1.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
```

This is what I have tried, but it doesn't work (line 28 on jsfiddle [commented]):

```
var inputs =  iframe1.CKEDITOR.instances.test6.getData();
```

This is the type of textarea (ckeditor) it should read, this is the HTML code in iframe #1:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://nightly.ckeditor.com/13-10-29-07-05/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>

<textarea class="ckeditor" id="test6" name="testa">asdfasdf</textarea>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/RTBJQ/22/

At least in Chrome it works if I understood what you want to do. The relevant part:

```
var input = iframe1.contentWindow.CKEDITOR.instances.test6.getData();
outputBody.innerHTML = '<div id="MagicalPonies">' + input + '</div>';
```

---

To loop through instances, you can do it like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/RTBJQ/24/ - The relevant part:

```
var html = "";
for (var insta in iframe1.contentWindow.CKEDITOR.instances) { 
    var input = iframe1.contentWindow.CKEDITOR.instances[insta].getData();
    html += '<h1>'+insta+'</h1><div>' + input + '</div>';
}
outputBody.innerHTML = html;
```

Comment: how do i make this work for multiple instances?  could be same id 'test6' or maybe iterate like 'test1', test2', 'test3', etc.  I want all the instances combined and put together then sent to iframe2.  Thanks.

Comment: @JoeFlemmings I edited the answer to include instance looping, hope it helps! It's not a solution completely for your combination thing, but extending it to be a combined solution should be quite simple from the example.

Comment: I need a working example.  Can you or anyone help me with this?  Maybe show me in jsfiddle?

Comment: I figured that it would be pretty straightforward from the example. Also, by working example, do you mean that you want to see the combination too? Here in SO I try not to offer complete solutions, it's more common to try to solve or answer a small specific issue. I made a revision to the linked jsfiddle; although the change is truly minimal: http://jsfiddle.net/RTBJQ/24/ - if you have access to the referenced iframe source, just add editors there, it should work.

Comment: How do I make both of these ckeditor textareas work?  http://jsfiddle.net/RTBJQ/25/  Basically I want the code to work for multiple textareas.

Comment: Let me rephrase with a better example:   http://jsfiddle.net/RTBJQ/27/      I want it to work for multiple textareas, just combine all the html from the textareas and make it go into the second iframe.  So if ckeditor1 has "foo" and ckeditor2 has "bar", then the second iframe should show "foobar".  Thanks.

Comment: Both of your CKEditors has an ID of test6, that's why it didn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/RTBJQ/28/ What I did was just give them unique IDs an Names and then edit my source so that it doesn't print the h1 element. Simple as that :).